# createBrowserRouter How to nest child routes inside another route that itself is a nested child route?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am new to react router I followed the tutorial for the latest version 6.4.3 and am using the createBrowserRouter.

For my App component below I attempted to add a children object to the index path but when I do this the app doesn't render all of a sudden.  I have tried this on the other paths having the same results. Not exactly sure what to do please help!

App.js Code below:

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import './index.css';

import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from 'react-router-dom';
import Root from './routes/Root';
import Home from './routes/Home';
import Projects from './routes/Projects';
import ErrorPage from './error/ErrorPage';
import Contact from './routes/Contact';
import Certificates from './routes/Certificates';
import Skills from './routes/Skills';
import Cycling from './routes/HobbyRoutes/Cycling';
import Minis from './routes/HobbyRoutes/Minis';
import Chivalry from './routes/HobbyRoutes/Chivalry';
//import NavBar from '../src/NavBar/NavBar';

const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
        path: '/',
        element: <Root />,
        errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
        children: [
            {
                index: true,
                element: <Home />,
                children: [
                    {
                        path: '/home/minis',
                        element: <Minis/>
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                path: '/projects',
                element: <Projects />,
                errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
            },
            {
                path: '/certificates',
                element: <Certificates />,
            },
            {
                path: '/skills',
                element: <Skills />,
            },
            {
                path: '/contact',
                element: <Contact />,
            },
        ],
    },
]);


function App() {
  return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
}

export default App;
```

For my App component below I attempted to add a children object to the index path but when I do this the page doesn't render all of a sudden.

Expectations is that the page renders.

Comment: Are you saying that all the "root" routes (*`"/"`, `"/projects"`, etc*) render and that there isn't an issue until trying to navigate to `"/home/minis"` that the `Minis` component doesn't render? Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: There is an open issue for the missing docs on children on the react-router repo, might want to upvote that
https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/9661

Answer (score 4):

Add < Outlet /> to your parent route's render method.

> An < Outlet > should be used in parent route elements to render their child route elements. This allows nested UI to show up when child routes are rendered. If the parent route matched exactly, it will render a child index route or nothing if there is no index route.

Read more: https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/outlet

Answer (score 0):

Adding an `<Outlet />` as the element of child elements worked for me. I have made some updates to your code, for context see section on `path: '/home'`:

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
        path: '/',
        element: <Root />,
        errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
        children: [
            {
                path: '/home',
                element: <Outlet />,
                children: [
                    {   
                        index: true,
                        element: <Home />
                    },
                    {
                        path: '/home/minis',
                        element: <Minis/>
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                path: '/projects',
                element: <Projects />,
                errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
            },
            {
                path: '/certificates',
                element: <Certificates />,
            },
            {
                path: '/skills',
                element: <Skills />,
            },
            {
                path: '/contact',
                element: <Contact />,
            },
        ],
    },
]);
```

Additionaly the assumption is that `<Root />` is of type `<Outlet />`, see sample below:

```
function Root() {
  return (
    <div>
        <div>Main navigation</div>
        <div>Side Navigation</div>
        <main>
          <Outlet />
        </main>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Root;
```

Answer (score 0):

When `<Home />` becomes an index child of `<Root />`, its path is `/`, not `/home`, and it can't have its child element, otherwise, all pages will turn blank. To resolve this:

Step 1: Change your router to one of the following:

```
 // To render `<Home />` as index element of `<Root />`
 const router = createBrowserRouter([
   {
     path: "/",
     element: <Root />,
     errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
     children: [
        {
           // When visit `/` root path, you'll see `<Home />` rendered as a default child of `<Root />`
           index: true,
           element: <Home />, 
           // Move children outside as the sibling of <Home />
        },
        {
           // Change path `/home/minis` to `/minis`
           path: '/minis',
           element: <Minis/>
        },

        /* existing code */
      ]
    },
 ]);
 // To render `<Home />` as common child element at `/home` and render `<Minis>` at `/home/minis`
  const router = createBrowserRouter([
   {
     path: "/",
     element: <Root />,
     errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
     children: [
        {
          // Remove: index: true,
           path: "/home", // Add path here 
           element: <Home />,
           children: [
             {
                path: '/home/minis',
                element: <Minis/>
             },
           ]
        },
      /* existing code */
      ]
    },
 ]);
```

Step 2: In `./routes/Home`, import `Outlet`, like this:

```
import {Outlet} from "react-router-dom";
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <>
       /* existing code */
       <Outlet />
    </>
```

Step 3: In `./routes/Root`, import `Outlet`, like this:

```
import {Outlet} from "react-router-dom";
export default function Root() {
  return (
    <>
       /* existing code */
       <Outlet />
    </>
```